# From csv to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, csv, arraylist

Ive been having trouble getting the data from a csv file into an arrayList so i can use it to make Polylines later. Whatever i try i can't get it to work properly. Does anyone have a pointer to what im doing wrong.
Im using a Toast to temporarly see the result.

Im expecting the code to give me an ArrayList, but it just returns me a empty list

Im adding the maps activity where this should happen and the function that writes the file in the mainActivity

MapsActivity;

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("trip_file");
    InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
    BufferedReader BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
    List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    String line = "";

    try {
        while( (line = BufferedReader.readLine()) != null) // Read until end of file
        {
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(line.split(", ")[0]);
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(line.split(", ")[1]);
            latLngList.add(new LatLng(lat, lon));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

                String teest = String.valueOf(latLngList);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), teest,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

This code in MainActivity writes the file;

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lon = location.getLongitude();

    myList.add(lat);
    myList.add(lon);

    String file_name = "trip_file";


    try {
        String skrive = String.valueOf(myList);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(file_name, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(skrive.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a little vague. SO does better with specific problems. What do you expect, what is happening instead, and avoid just giving us a mess of code and asking us to 'fix it'.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use CSVParser (Apache 2.0 licence) which is nice and simple:
https://github.com/OpenBD/openbd-core/tree/master/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv